# Loading image with large ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have added the following code to show and hide loading image in my web page during ajax request.

```
 $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    $("#please_wait").css("display","block");
 });

$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
     $("#please_wait").css("display","none");
});
```

Here, `$("#please_wait")` is a `div` containing a loading image.

**My problem is**

Some of my ajax request returns more than 15 MB of data.But the loading image does not show up to the complete data received.It is removed when it starts receive data.

Why?

And how to solve the error?

Comment: try replacing ajaxComplete with success callback, maybe there's some error and ajaxComplete gets called earlier.

Comment: Do you have multiple ajax requests on your site? `ajaxComplete` may be fired from any other request.

Comment: @secelite ,yes,This is the common function i was used to show loader.

Comment: @Giannis,Ya,That was the problem,I was trying to find a methow to complete data transfer.

Comment: @Shin so is it possible that you have more than one simultaneously requests and the `ajaxComplete` is fired before finishing your "huge" request?

Comment: @secelite How to handle tthis situation?

Comment: @Shin you could count up an internal variable like `ajaxCount` wirth every `ajaxStart` you fire. In `ajaxComplete` you can subtract from `ajaxCount`. If it is 0 you can execute your callback `$("#please_wait").css("display","none");`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59580/discussion-between-shin-and-secelite).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of placing `display:none` in the `ajaxComplete` You can try following way:

Write `$("#please_wait").css("display","none");` in the very first line of ajax successful call condition.

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    $("#please_wait").css("display","block");
});

if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {        
    $("#please_wait").css("display","none");        
}
```